# Conditional Styling in Svelte Loop

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte

Has anyone used Svelte in their projects? I just have a small question. Let's say you are looping through an array and displaying the data in the array. And there are 4 objects in the array. If I only want to style the first iteration (bluma). How do I do it?

```
let items = [
        { icon: 'book', title: 'bulma', tags: ['public', 'sources'] },
        { icon: 'book', title: 'marksheet', tags: ['private'] },
        { icon: 'book', title: 'minireset.css', tags: ['public', 'sources'] },
        { icon: 'code-branch', title: 'daniellowtw/infboard', tags: ['public', 'forks'] },
        { icon: 'code-branch', title: 'mojs', tags: ['private'] }
    ]

{#each filteredItems as item}
    <a class="panel-block {item.}">
    <span class="panel-icon">
            {#if item.icon === "code-branch"}
            <i class="fas fa-code-branch" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {:else if item.icon ==="book"}
            <i class="fas fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {/if}
```

Answer (score 4):

Whenever a pure CSS approach is available, I would rather use that. Here you could make use of the `:first-child` selector:

```js
<div class="panel-items">
{#each filteredItems as item}
    <a class="panel-block">
        <span class="panel-icon">
            {#if item.icon === "code-branch"}
                <i class="fas fa-code-branch" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {:else if item.icon ==="book"}
                <i class="fas fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {/if}
        </span>
    </a>
{/each}
</div>

<style>
    .panel-block {
        /* general panel block styling */
    }

    .panel-block:first-child {
        /* first panel block style overrides */
    }
</style>
```

Note that the entire loop is held within its own container div in order to make sure the first item in the loop is indeed the first child of its parent container.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the `index` provided as a second argument of the `#each` block:

```
{#each filteredItems as item, i}
  <span style="color:{i === 0 ? 'green' : 'red'}">
    {item.title}
  </span>
{/each}
```

Reference: [Each block](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/each-blocks) in svelte tutorial.